# List to array and into jComboBox

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

```
AdministratorFrame(Administrator account) {
    AdministratorFrameLocked(true);
    administrator = account;
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory 
            = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("KwestionariuszForRoot");
    EntityManager entityManager 
            = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    List<Company> companies
            = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Company.findByAdministratorId")
            .setParameter("administrator_id", administrator).getResultList();
    entityManager.close();
    System.out.println(companies);
    List<String> companyNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Company company : companies) {
        companyNames.add(company.getName().toString());
    }
    System.out.println(companyNames);
    String[] companiesArray = new String[companyNames.size()];
    companiesArray = companyNames.toArray(companiesArray);
    System.out.println(companiesArray);
    jComboBoxCompaniesByName
            .setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(companiesArray)); 
    initComponents();
    AdministratorFrameLocked(false);
}
```

Returns (note that printlns return a value so are not null):

```
[model.Company[ id=1 ]] 
[Mentor]
[Ljava.lang.String;@139fcc0 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
java.lang.NullPointerException at
frames.AdministratorFrame.<init>(AdministratorFrame.java:54)
```

54th line is:

```
jComboBoxCompaniesByName
                .setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(companiesArray));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that `jComboBoxCompaniesByName` is null, which would be the case if you don't initialise it before `initComponents` at the next line.

Comment: yeah, that was it, I'm too fast with posting here, it was trivial... -_-'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you initialize `jComboBoxCompaniesByName`.
Somewhere it should be initialize like so :

```
jComboBoxCompaniesByName = new JCombobox();
```

Just a guess...Try moving `initComponents()` before line 54.

Comment: yeah, that was it, shame on me. :)